# No module named 'PIL'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, python-imaging-library

I'm running into an error where when I try

`from PIL import Image, ImageFilter`

in a Python file I get an error stating `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'`.

So far I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling both PIL and Pillow, along with just doing `import Image`, but the error keeps on occurring and I have no idea why. All the solutions I've found so far have had no effect on my issue.

I'm running Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Did u use pip or pip3 while installing?

Comment: Is is possible that you have python 2 and python 3 installed (I just know python 2 comes bundled with OSX) so there might be an issue with which version you are installing vs importing it on.

Comment: When I do `pip3 --version`, it outputs `pip 9.0.1 from /home/hf/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)` so I am running 3.5, not 2

Comment: run pip --version and see the output

Comment: `pip --version` outputs `pip 9.0.1 from /home/hf/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)`, but I think it might be a $PATH issue as my Python 3.6 install (along with PIL and Pillow) are located at `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages`. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `PIL` is deprecated since a long time ago and has been replaced by `Pillow`. So if you're using old code, you need to look up what has been replaced and what other modifications are required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, I found a fix

To fix the issue, I uninstalled `PIL` and `Pillow` through `sudo pip3 uninstall pillow` and `sudo apt-get purge python3-pil`. I then restarted and then used `sudo -H pip3 install pillow` to reinstall `Pillow`

The only step I was missing before was rebooting, and not reinstalling `PIL` afterwards.

It seems to have worked without any issues so far.

Comment: Be careful executing `apt-get purge python3-pil` on a system running Cinnamon (eg: Linux Mint). It may remove cinnamon packages as well preventing you from login. If that happens to you follow this answer to restore the system: https://superuser.com/a/1588720/217131

Comment: yes, please use a virtual environment

Answer (score 11):

Had the same problem before and I tried:

```
 pip install pillow 
 pip install image
```

`import PIL` --> still did not work

then I found out that it was installed as pil

`c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pil`

```
import pil

pil.__version__

'5.1.0'
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and I was facing exactly same issue after installing pillow following the [official documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#linux-installation). I tried all hacks shared by other users but no solution. But the problem got immediately resolved when I installed `python-pil` using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pil
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue with the command `python3 -m pip install Pillow`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem had to do with virtual environments.

The python program ran in a virtual environment, but I called `pip install Pillow` from a normal command prompt. When I ran the program in a non-virtual environment, `from PIL import Image` worked.

It also worked when I called `venv/scripts/activate` before calling `pip install Pillow`. So apparently PIL is not found when installed in the python root but the program runs in a virtual environment.

Comment: Yes! This was what worked for me. If you have been running your app in a virtual environment, you have to activate the virtual environment and then install Pillow.

Answer (score 1):

This subject has been a while, but I would like to share what I have encountered.

I used to have Pillow installed and it worked well. But today when I was doing something, it started to give me this error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'". I tried all the methods in this subject, but the problem was still there.

So I went to Pillow [website](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) trying to use the official installation guide. After I enter "**python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip**", system told me I don't have **pip** installed. Then I realized the python it referred to is the one in my mingw64 library (**C:\msys64\mingw64\bin**), as I installed it yesterday for C++ compilation and it was added to my system environment path.

After removing the mingw64 bin library from system environment and re-installing Pillow, "from PIL import image" works perfectly.