# PIL module ImportError on Apache2 Server

Tags: django, apache2, python-imaging-library, python-3.5

I am getting this traceback on my Apache2 server when trying to upload an image. I am using Python 3.5.2 and Pillow 5.0.0 and Django 2.1.1
I was able to upload images successfully when I am working on my localhost, but when I uploaded this code to the apache2 server, then it gives this traceback. Pillow is in the requiremnts.txt though. No where in the code do I explicitly try to import PIL, but it seems to be getting called.

I have tried installing Pillow and PIL. I have tried to uninstall PIL, uninstall Pillow, I have tried re-install both. Nothing seems to be working.

> View.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core import serializers
from manager.models import Manager, Inspection
from . import InspectorService
from . import InspectionService
import json
from .forms import InspectionImageForm

... more unrelevant code here ...

def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InspectionImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        inspection_id = request.POST.get('inspection_id')
        if form.is_valid():
            m = Inspection.objects.get(id = inspection_id)
            m.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            m.save()

            return JsonResponse({'error': False, 'message': 'Uploaded Successfully', 'location': m.image.name})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'error': True, 'errors': form.errors})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': True, 'errors': 'Post error'})
```

> forms.py

```
from django import forms

class InspectionImageForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
    inspection_id = forms.IntegerField()
```

> Traceback

```
File "/opt/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/opt/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/opt/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/var/www/html/CMPUT401/computronix/manager/views.py" in upload_image
  119.         if form.is_valid():

File "/opt/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  185.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/opt/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  180.             self.full_clean()

File "/opt/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  381.         self._clean_fields()

File "/opt/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_fields
  397.                     value = field.clean(value, initial)

File "/opt/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py" in clean
  584.         return super().clean(data)

File "/opt/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py" in clean
  147.         value = self.to_python(value)

File "/opt/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py" in to_python
  613.         from PIL import Image

Exception Type: ImportError at /manager/upload_image/
Exception Value: No module named 'PIL'
```

Comment: If you use virtual env make sure it is activated

Comment: It may be version issues. Try other solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49247310/no-module-named-pil